# How to add Year to <ion-datetime> by default before choosing Date/Year

Tags: angular, datetime, ionic3

I am using ion-datetime with my form. I want to add by default to my form the Year even before the user chooses the year from the datepicker.

here is my code:

**HOME.html**

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div>
    <form [formGroup]="rForm" (ngSubmit)="addPost(rForm.value)">
      <ion-list>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-label colot="primary" floating>
            Year
          </ion-label>
          <ion-datetime displayFormat="YYYY" formControlName="year" min="2000" max="{{date| date:'yyyy'}}" [disabled]="!user"></ion-datetime>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>

          <button ion-button block [disabled]="!user" (click)="addToTracker(rForm.value)">Submit To Tracker</button>
        </ion-item>

      </ion-list>
    </form>
  </div>
```

**HOME.ts** *significant code:*

```
this.date = new Date();
```

Now this works and I can correctly take the Year once its picked by the user *(I do not want anything other then the year)*
The problem is the user can submit the form with the year field empty.
In order to over come that *(I do not want to use ngModel because i tried it and it did not allow me to use only the Year, it wanted an ISO date format so once submitted i got a full date and not just the year, i do not know if there is another way for ngModel)*

So my idea is to put the current YEAR by default there... so in case the user submitted without a year it will take 2017 by default.

I'm open to suggestions!

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code for TS file, date should be converted to ISOString to render properly in Ionic

```
   date : any = new Date().toISOString();
   currentYear : any = (new Date()).getFullYear();
```

Below is the code for HTML file

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="YYYY" min="2000" max="{{currentYear}}" [(ngModel)]="date"></ion-datetime>
```

Refer the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tab-issue) for working version.

Comment: I do not have a problem with the Date picker. <ion-datetime> do the job perfectly! and its native. my problem is that I want a default year to be already picked by default before the user pick a date himself/herself. No need for all your code. <ion-datetime> just does that.

Comment: I also tried this method. the problem is that once you click submit, the value of the ion-datetime field taken from the form will be a FULL DATE and not just the Year because of:    `    date : any = new Date().toISOString();    `    So what is actually happening is that your showing only YYYY however the real data behind it is a full time. What i need is to show only YYYY (year) and to actually submit only YYYY (the year) and to display by default without use intervention also YYYY (year)

Comment: Again get the year from the ISO date string with the following code in addPost method --  new Date(this.date).getFullYear()

Comment: How it works on my system ``` this.minDate = moment(new Date()).subtract(1, 'months').toDate().toISOString();
    this.maxDate = moment(new Date()).add(3, 'years').toDate().toISOString();  ```

Answer (score 0):

Too late but maybe someone else need it. (for Ionic 4)
firstly you could use ngmodel for this;

add this to ts file    date:number =2017;

```
<ion-datetime display-format="YYYY" [(ngModel)]="date" formControlName="year" min="2000" max="{{date| date:'yyyy'}}" [disabled]="!user"></ion-datetime>
```

and other option add  [value]="2017"

```
<ion-datetime display-format="YYYY" [value]="2017" formControlName="year" min="2000" max="{{date| date:'yyyy'}}" [disabled]="!user"></ion-datetime>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for TS file, Date should be converted to ISO String to render properly in Ionic 2/3/4

Add in ts allow user to select date with future years.

```
minDate: string = new Date().toISOString();

maxData : any = (new Date()).getFullYear() + 3;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bAP7.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgrmD.png)